# What is difference between "Input Text" and "Press keys"?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

When I use "Input Text" to input text in the textbox, sometimes it will occur some error?

[image]

But, I just change the "Input Text" to the "Press keys" it will work normally.

Note: XPATH is correct.

Selenium doc:

Input Text-> Types the given text into the text field identified by locator.

Press keys-> Simulates the user pressing key(s) to an element or on the active browser.

Comment: adding image/screenshot of code/error is not good practice. please add it as part of question in the form of text/code also please read [mcve] and follow the same practice to get good answers for the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically they are almost identical. Robot Framework uses [SeleniumLibrary](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary) that wraps web driver with the keywords "shell". Below you can find some snippet that spots the relevant code from there:

```
def _input_text_into_text_field(self, locator, text, clear):
    element = self.find_element(locator)
    if is_truthy(clear):
        element.clear()
    element.send_keys(text)

def _press_keys(self, locator, parsed_keys):
    if is_truthy(locator):
        element = self.find_element(locator)
    else:
        element = None
    for parsed_key in parsed_keys:
        actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
        special_keys = []
        for key in parsed_key:
            if self._selenium_keys_has_attr(key.original):
                special_keys = self._press_keys_special_keys(actions, element, parsed_key,
                                                             key, special_keys)
            else:
                self._press_keys_normal_keys(actions, element, key)
        for special_key in special_keys:
            self.info('Releasing special key %s.' % special_key.original)
            actions.key_up(special_key.converted)
        actions.perform()

def _press_keys_normal_keys(self, actions, element, key):
    self.info('Sending key%s %s' % (plural_or_not(key.converted), key.converted))
    if element:
        actions.send_keys_to_element(element, key.converted)
    else:
        actions.send_keys(key.converted)

def _press_keys_special_keys(self, actions, element, parsed_key, key, special_keys):
    if len(parsed_key) == 1 and element:
        self.info('Pressing special key %s to element.' % key.original)
        actions.send_keys_to_element(element, key.converted)
    elif len(parsed_key) == 1 and not element:
        self.info('Pressing special key %s to browser.' % key.original)
        actions.send_keys(key.converted)
    else:
        self.info('Pressing special key %s down.' % key.original)
        actions.key_down(key.converted)
        special_keys.append(key)
    return special_keys
```

So in other words when you call `Input Text` it first tries to clear the field (unlike when you call `Press Keys`). But with `Input Text` you wouldn't be able to generate some key stokes like "Up, Down", etc.

Press Keys, being able to send some "special" keys can generate events against elements which cannot be generated by `Input Text`. Such events might be handled in some special way on your page under test, so the latter method hypothetically can extend the coverage of your tests (depending on if those events are really treated in any special way in your application).

Comment: Thanks! I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Input Text find the element on DOM and send your text while press keys doing keyboard operations

You are getting stale element exception that means element is not ready and jump in stale situation, to resolve it either you need to wait till the staleness resolve to perform action like refresh, loop with multiple attempts

JAVA Code which can wait as below:

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(element)
```

OR

you can also refresh the page, try:

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
```

use refresh before the element throwing Stale Reference exception

Change the code syntax as per your requirement

Comment: answer does not justify the intent of question and totally irrelevant, question is not relate to java binding , but answer suggested is in java

Comment: answer is relevent as he is getting stale element execption, check his error image, yes the code is in java as I already stated in my answer, it is better to provide correct solution or reference and OP can made simple change

Comment: please read it again its `InvalidElementStateException` not `StaleElementReferenceException` and both has way much difference ans so the ans is irrelevant addition to it this problem has been solved by OP, now OP asked what is difference between the ways one worked and not the other

Answer (score 0):

In what state is the element when your script fails?

You can try `Wait Until Element Is Enabled` keyword. Also, in some cases you need to click the element to make it editable.